# How to remove Intel's Open Source Technology Center Driver?

Tags: 13.04, drivers, xorg, intel, gpu-driver

I have downloaded and installed Intel's drivers from this link, following all instructions: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2

However, I would like to return to stock Ubuntu's driver configuration. How would I go about doing this? I've found this link, but it's only for Ubuntu 12.10: http://theclonker.de/?p=89

According to Synaptic, Intel's repository added the following packages locally (may contain typos; forgive me):

```
i915-3.9-3.8-dkms
intel-linux-graphics-installer
libdrm-dev
libdrm-intel1
libdrm-intel1:i386
libdrm-nouveau2
libdrm-nouveau2:i386
libdrm-radeon1
libdrm-radeon1:i386
libdrm2
libdrm2:i386
libkms1
libva-drm1
libva-egl1
libva-glx1
libva-tpi1
libva-wayland1
libva-X11-1
libva1
x11proto-input-dev
xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I'm not sure whether the above list is complete and/or exhaustive as to the changes the Intel installer made.

Also important to note, Intel's instructions to delete their repository in Software Sources just flat-out doesn't work. It removes the repository, but keeps the packages installed locally.

Comment: I checked the link.. The script was actually only for `12.10` But the steps after that script actually applies for all versions and distros.. So you have to replace `quantal*` to `raring*` in `Pin: release a=quantal*` if you are using `Ubuntu 13.04`.  or `quntal*` to `precise*` if your are using `Ubuntu 12.04` that was mentioned clearly there.. Obviously `apt-get` is already installed..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to safely remove proprietary Intel driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/531540/how-to-safely-remove-proprietary-intel-driver)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All right. I have a history of answering my own questions, and here goes again:

Thanks to Saurav Kumar, I had another look at the second link I put in my question. Here's what you gotta do in Ubuntu 13.04:

Open the terminal and create a new file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal
```

Copy+paste the following contents (MAKE SURE THAT THERE ARE NO TABS, SPACES OR INDENTS BEFORE ANY LINES, and replace raring with your own release):

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=raring*
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: origin download.01.org
Pin-Priority: -100
```

Save the file and close gedit.

Run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

In my case, this simply downgraded and removed some packages. I cannot guarantee what it will do on your system, because I'm a noob like that. So run at your own leisure, but don't blame me if things go wrong.

Now the cleaning up bit:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list*
sudo apt-get update
```

Followed by removing the actual drivers (i915-3.9-3.8-dkms WILL be different depending on your version of Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get purge i915-3.9-3.8-dkms intel-linux-graphics-installer
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot, et voilà, we're done. Thanks to the author of the below blog post and Saurav Kumar.

Reference: http://theclonker.de/?p=89

Comment: It is good that you verified it first, also posted an answer.. Definitely it would help others to get ride of such things..

Comment: Great, this worked for me on 14.04.1 with changing the 2nd line `Pin: release a=raring*` to `Pin: release a=trusty*`

Comment: Worked wonderfully for me on 15.10 as well. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that installing the intel-driver messes with nvidia and bumblebee.
So if you get

```
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

when trying to run `optirun something`, the answer above will solve your problem.
Took me 2 hours of google to figure that out...