# Nvidia (Bumblebee) failed to load after install latest Intel driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Everything was just fine. I have updated Intel driver using [this installer](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_amd64.deb). After installing the driver it was asked to restart and I did. Now `optirun` is not working. Intel driver looks good I think. I run `dpkg-reconfigure` for `bumblebee`, `bbswitch-dkms` and `nvidia-340` but nothings helps. Also restart the system couple of times. I found the following errors.

```
$optirun firefox
[  117.439917] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[  117.439954] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

$dmesg | tail
[  117.506015] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd (err -22)
[  117.506034] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_private_object_init
[  117.506036] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_private_object_init (err -22)
[  117.506106] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_handle_create
[  117.506107] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_handle_create (err -22)
[  117.506161] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_pci_exit
[  117.506162] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_exit (err -22)
[  117.506187] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_prime_export
[  117.506188] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_export (err -22)
```

## System information:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
$lspci | grep "VGA\|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)

$dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep "bumblebee\|nvidia-\|bbswitch"
bbswitch-dkms                   install
bumblebee                   install
bumblebee-nvidia                install
nvidia-340                  install
nvidia-settings
```

Comment: It looks like the Intel driver installed an updated DRM module. Try removing the Nvidia driver and then re-installing it. If that does not work, you will need to report this as a bug to Nvidia.

Comment: @bain How to revert back to default(14.04 default) drm??

Comment: Uninstall the Intel driver.

Comment: @bain What should be command? What is the name of intel driver?

Comment: It appears that Intel do not provide an easy way to uninstall the driver. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343390/how-to-remove-intels-open-source-technology-center-driver suggests using apt pinning to downgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Intel driver is the problem. Nvidia doesn't support new drm environment. To remove the new driver run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge i915-3.15-3.13-dkms
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Then restart the system. `optirun` should work after restart the system. If not then run the following commands and restart again

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-340
sudo dpkg-reconfigure bbswitch-dkms
```