# Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, bumblebee

I tried multiple different drives, nvidia-340, nvidia-331, nvidia-331-updates, nvidia-343 and with the same result:

```
# optirun -vv --debug bash
[  785.862681] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  785.863474] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[  785.863827] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[  785.863890] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  785.863929] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  785.863970] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[  785.864056] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
[  785.864092] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  785.864120] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[  785.864148] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[  785.864175] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[  785.864212] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[  785.864329] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge virtualgl
[  785.878755] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  785.878771] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  785.878775] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[  785.878790] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[  785.878794] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

My Linux kernel

```
 # uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
```

Bumblebee.conf:

```
# cat /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-331-updates
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

```
    # cat /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
    BusID "PCI:01:00:0"

#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"

    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

PORT:

```
# lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

Drivers:

```
# dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                                            3.2.1-90~trustyppa1                                    amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-331-updates                                          331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                      amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38
ii  nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates                               331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates                               331.38-0ubuntu7.1                                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                                0.6.2linuxmint1                                        amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                             343.13-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1                         amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

dmesg:

```
# dmesg | grep nv
[    0.658496] rtc_cmos 00:06: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[   29.242070] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[  362.966609] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_pci_init
[  362.966613] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_init (err -22)
[  362.966659] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd
[  362.966660] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd (err -22)
[  362.966678] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_private_object_init
[  362.966679] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_private_object_init (err -22)
[  362.966746] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_handle_create
[  362.966747] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_handle_create (err -22)
[  362.966796] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_pci_exit
[  362.966797] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_exit (err -22)
[  362.966822] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_prime_export
[  362.966823] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_export (err -22)
```

and

```
# dmesg | grep bb
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcb000000-0xcbbfffff]
[    0.256795] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0xb9bea000-0xbbffffff]
[    0.256796] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0xba429000-0xbbffffff]
[    0.661515] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 2cb1133b35f95a9e24deabeeb12ba449bcbabbc9'
[    4.377136] bbswitch: version 0.8
[    4.377141] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[    4.377144] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[    4.377230] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[    4.377275] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[    4.378990] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[   28.392635] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[  308.876566] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[  362.505917] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
```

Comment: You might want to take this to nvidias devtalk Linux forum

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it myself. I stumbled upon this thread since I also installed the latest drivers; [Nvidia (Bumblebee) failed to load after install latest Intel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507095/nvidia-bumblebee-failed-to-load-after-install-latest-intel-driver)

But I did the instructions:

```
sudo apt-get purge i915-3.15-3.13-dkms
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-340
sudo dpkg-reconfigure bbswitch-dkms
sudo reboot
```

But it didn't work for me, so I searched some more. I found this bug report and tried these instructions (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310023):

```
sudo ldconfig -n
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Eureka, it worked!