# GT 730 Driver Installation Issues on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I have purchased a PNY GeForce GT 730 Graphics Card for my Dell Inspiron i3-3240 desktop, but neither the nouveau drivers nor the proprietary NVIDIA drivers will get me past GRUB without a blank screen. After experimenting, I found that the VGA output after GRUB was being directed by the onboard integrated graphics card VGA.

I looked in the BIOS, but found no option to disable the onboard graphics; Dell Support has informed me that the option was not supported on my computer.

I have tried drivers nvidia-331 and nvidia-340 from the xorg-edgers PPA, the installed nouveau, and the drivers on NVIDIA's website, but all to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this: [Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539152/cannot-access-secondary-gpu-error-could-not-load-gpu-driver)

```
sudo apt-get purge i915-3.15-3.13-dkms
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-340
sudo dpkg-reconfigure bbswitch-dkms
sudo ldconfig -n
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```