# Find the power consumption of the network card

Tags: command-line, power-management

Is there a tool to print the power consumption of the network card ?

Comment: You can ask nvidia for a tool like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26DbJ3E4YKI It works for any pcie card like a network card

Answer (score 0):

You could use [powertop](https://01.org/powertop)

PowerTOP is a Linux tool to diagnose issues with power consumption and power management.

[image]

Comment: I tried this tool but it does not give the value of power consumption of the network card in watt. It gives  only information regarding in terms of percentage of usage.

Comment: It seems to show it in this https://askubuntu.com/questions/513037/excessive-power-consumption-by-ethernet-socket sceenshot. It does also not yet in my case, but i think you have to let it run for a while.